# I got 5.6 and 7.4 running on server

Tags: php

Hello I've been trying to Update my PHP, I got Both 5.6 and 7.4 running on Server

```
|-php-fpm5.6---2*[php-fpm5.6]
|-php-fpm7.4---2*[php-fpm7.4]
```

But the problem is: I dont know how to point that in Ngnix

I need to point this one:

```
/run/./php/php7.4-fpm.sock
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the php path in each site configuration.

Go to the nginx root folder. Usually it is located in *etc/nginx/sites-available* (Linux). Here, you would open the configuration file for the website that you would like to edit. Let's say the config file is simply called *default*. You open it. Go to following block:

**server { ... }**

Here search for:

**location ~ .php$ { .. }**

Withing the last block you will find the following line:

**fastcgi_pass unix:{old_php_path};**

Replace the old PHP path with the new one and then run:

**service nginx restart**

This should help you.